# amp html button not clickable inside amp-list

Tags: amp-html

Apologies in advance - I think this is a minor typo somewhere, as I'm sure I had this working...

The short version of the question: In the AMP HTML below, both buttons are rendered but only the one outside the amp-list is clickable.

Longer version of the question below, in case it's useful.

I'm trying to implement a carousel with a number of time-related slides. One of those slides at an arbitrary position will relate to 'now'.

I want a user to be able to click a button that will take them to the slide that represents 'now'.

I'm getting the relevant carousel index that relates to 'now' from a json endpoint, then intending to set the button's ontap event in a mustache template to go to the relevant slide.

The button I'm displaying needs to be inside an amp-list, since that is how I'm retrieving the json that tells me which slide index to point to. But the button is only clickable if I place the button outside of the amp-list.

I'm pretty sure this is something stupid on my part, can anyone shed some light please?

```
<!doctype html>
<html âš¡ lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,minimum-scale=1,initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="canonical" href="/article.html">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="amp_favicon.png">
    <script async custom-element="amp-fit-text" src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0/amp-fit-text-0.1.js"></script>
    <script async custom-element="amp-carousel" src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0/amp-carousel-0.1.js"></script>
    <script async src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0.js"></script>
    <script async custom-template="amp-mustache" src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0/amp-mustache-0.1.js"></script>
    <script async custom-element="amp-list" src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0/amp-list-0.1.js"></script>    

    <style amp-boilerplate>body{-webkit-animation:-amp-start 8s steps(1,end) 0s 1 normal both;-moz-animation:-amp-start 8s steps(1,end) 0s 1 normal both;-ms-animation:-amp-start 8s steps(1,end) 0s 1 normal both;animation:-amp-start 8s steps(1,end) 0s 1 normal both}@-webkit-keyframes -amp-start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}@-moz-keyframes -amp-start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}@-ms-keyframes -amp-start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}@-o-keyframes -amp-start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}@keyframes -amp-start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}</style><noscript><style amp-boilerplate>body{-webkit-animation:none;-moz-animation:none;-ms-animation:none;animation:none}</style></noscript>    


  </head>
  <body>

    <!-- this button is clickable, and the event is fired: -->      
    <button on="tap:carousel.goToSlide(index=1)" >Go to slide 1</button>


    <amp-list width="auto" height="200" src="<<JSON ENDPOINT>>">

    <!-- this button is not clickable so no event is fired: -->    
    <button on="tap:carousel.goToSlide(index=1)" >Go to slide 1</button>



    <template type="amp-mustache"> 
        <amp-carousel layout="fill" type="slides" id="carousel"  >
           <amp-fit-text width="100" height="500" >           carousel pos 1       </amp-fit-text>
           <amp-fit-text width="100" height="500" >           carousel pos 2       </amp-fit-text>
       </amp-carousel>
    </template>

    </amp-list>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: amp-carousel does not render amp-img inside amp-list https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/issues/12756

Comment: Hi Bachcha, thanks for commenting. The question is about a normal button inside an amp-list,  not about an amp-image in an amp-list. Or am I misunderstanding? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I am amusing that slider is static because amp-carousel does not render amp-img inside amp-list.

But button is clickable under amp-list

[Here is working url](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/YvorQM)

Json Url render the button under amp-list: [Click Here](https://jsonblob.com/api/6345e24e-803b-11e8-82fe-f3dd1274ef25)

**Code:**

```
<!doctype html>
<html amp lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,minimum-scale=1,initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="canonical" href="/article.html">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="amp_favicon.png">
    <script async custom-element="amp-fit-text" src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0/amp-fit-text-0.1.js"></script>
    <script async custom-element="amp-carousel" src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0/amp-carousel-0.1.js"></script>
    <script async src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0.js"></script>
    <script async custom-template="amp-mustache" src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0/amp-mustache-0.1.js"></script>
    <script async custom-element="amp-list" src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0/amp-list-0.1.js"></script>
    <style amp-boilerplate>body{-webkit-animation:-amp-start 8s steps(1,end) 0s 1 normal both;-moz-animation:-amp-start 8s steps(1,end) 0s 1 normal both;-ms-animation:-amp-start 8s steps(1,end) 0s 1 normal both;animation:-amp-start 8s steps(1,end) 0s 1 normal both}@-webkit-keyframes -amp-start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}@-moz-keyframes -amp-start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}@-ms-keyframes -amp-start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}@-o-keyframes -amp-start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}@keyframes -amp-start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}</style><noscript><style amp-boilerplate>body{-webkit-animation:none;-moz-animation:none;-ms-animation:none;animation:none}</style></noscript>    
</head>
  <body>
<amp-list width="auto" height="200" src="https://jsonblob.com/api/6345e24e-803b-11e8-82fe-f3dd1274ef25">
 <template type="amp-mustache"> 
    <button on="tap:carousel.goToSlide(index={{index}})" >Go to slide {{position}}</button>
</template>
 </amp-list>
  <amp-carousel layout="responsive" height="200" width="500" type="slides" id="carousel">
      <amp-fit-text width="200"   height="200"   layout="responsive">Slider 1</amp-fit-text>
      <amp-fit-text width="200"   height="200"   layout="responsive">Slider 2</amp-fit-text>
<amp-fit-text width="200"   height="200"   layout="responsive">Slider 3</amp-fit-text>
</amp-carousel>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you Bachcha! Your amp-carousel layout was responsive and mine wasn't, I changed that and the button is now clickable.